# What's the best way to realize a startscreen?

Tags: android

Can someone tell me what's the best way to realize a startscreen in android. What I meant is when you open the app than a image appears a few seconds and in the background the app is loading?

Comment: Here's a simple tutorial to create a splash screen for Android applicaiton http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/) is another example, which does not utilize a separate activity.